# How to open a file from Python in Windows using the default application when the file is already open?

Tags: windows, cmd, python-3.8

I'm trying to open a log file to show it to the user using the default application for .log files.
It works on Linux when I run `xdg-open file.log`, so I expected it to work on Windows when I call `start file.log`.

The error I get is `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`
The file is indeed open by the logging application, but that doesn't stop `notepad file.log` from working, and notepad is the default application.

Is it possible to open the log file using the default application when the file is already open?

Comment: Well, have you tried without `start`, just typing `file.log`?

Comment: Yes I have, same behavior.

Comment: …and what about running `notepad.exe "D:\path\to\your\file.log"`?

Comment: It works. Why did you think it will be different from running ```notepad file.log``` from the question?

Comment: Great! I just thought `start` is doing some existence and availability checks in the background before actually opening a file with the associated default application; well, and just providing a file name without a path is a common error…